# Google Api get access_token request returns invalid_request

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, google-api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get Google APi's access_token using javascript and always getting error message :`invalid_request`. There is my code:

```
var options = {
    url: tokenURL,
    type: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        "code":successCode,
        "client_id": clietId,
        "client_secret": clientSecret,
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "redirect_url": "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
    },
    complete: function (e) {
        alert(e.status);
    },
};

$.ajax(options);
```

I also tried to make POST request using simple html form and it works.

```
<form method="post" action="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token">
<input name="code" type="text" value="##code##" />
<input name="client_id" type="text" value="##client_id##" />
<input name="client_secret" type="text" value="##client_secret##" />
<input name="grant_type" type="text" value="authorization_code" />
<input name="redirect_uri" type="text" value="urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" />

<input type="submit" /></form>
```

I have no idea whats wrong with javascript request. Am I missing some parameters or headers?

Comment: try using Firebug and looking at the Net tab to see the difference between the request you make from a form vs the ajax request

Comment: I tried using Fiddler and didn't noticed any difference except cookies

Comment: @pauliusnrk did you get any solution?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the encoding of `data` (in the first example) doesn't match the content-type.

The encoding of `data` appears to be application/json, but the content-type specified is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

You need to change the encoding of `data` to be urlencoded.

```
   data: "code=successCode&client_id=clientId&client_secret=clientSecret&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_url=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
```

Comment: By setting the data like you said, the request is not even sent: `var options = {
   url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
   type: "POST",
   headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
   dataType: "json",
   data: "code=code&client_id=clientId&client_secret=clientSecret&redirect_uri=myuri&grant_type=authorization_code",
   complete: function (e) {
    alert(e);
    alert(e.status);
   },
  };
  $.ajax(options);`