# Connecting to Google via OAuth 2, "invalid_request" when requesting an access token

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

There are several questions along these lines already on SE, but I've read everything I can find that seems relevant, and I'm still not quite there.

I got an authentication code, so now I need to exchange it for an access token and a refresh token.  However, Google returns the wonderfully non-specific error "invalid_request".  Here's my code:

```
private const string  BaseAccessTokenUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
private const string  ContentType        = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

public static string  GetRefreshToken(string clientId, string clientSecret, string authCode)
    {
    Dictionary<string, string>  parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
        { "code",          authCode },
        { "client_id",     clientId },
        { "client_secret", clientSecret },
        { "redirect_uri",  "http://localhost" },
        { "grant_type",    "authorization_code" }
        };
    string  rawJson = WebUtilities.Post(BaseAccessTokenUrl, parameters, ContentType);
    return rawJson;  // TODO: Parse out the actual refresh token
    }
```

My `Post()` method URL-encodes the parameters keys and values and concatenates them:

```
public static string  Post(string uri, Dictionary<string, string> properties, string contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    {
    string  content = String.Join("&", from kvp in properties select UrlEncode(kvp.Key) + "=" + UrlEncode(kvp.Value) );
    return Post(uri, content);
    }
```

The two-parameter `Post()` method just handles converting the content to bytes, adding content-length, etc., then returns the contents of the response even if it came as a `WebException`.  I can include it if it's of any interest.

The authorization code looks right, it's similar to others I've seen: 62 characters, and it starts with "4/".  The client ID, secret, and redirect URL I've carefully copied from [the Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).  The app is registered as an "Other" app, and I'm connecting from a Windows machine.

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863966/google-api-get-token-request-returns-invalid-request) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066186/google-api-access-token-returning-400-invalid-request), I've tried NOT URL-encoding, with no change.  [The OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) suggests that URL-encoding is correct.

Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799947/google-api-request-for-token-from-oauth2-returns-invalid-request) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696584/net-google-oauth-token-webrequest-bad-request-protocol-error), the properties are concatenated on a single line.

Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812459/google-api-request-for-token-from-oauth2-returns-invalid-request), I've tried `approval_prompt=force` in the authorization request, but the new auth code did not work any better.  Do auth codes expire?  I'm using new codes within a few seconds, usually.

Per [the Google docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759532/google-api-get-access-token-request-returns-invalid-request), I'm using content-type "application/x-www-form-encoded".

My authorization request is for scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly".

Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833281/how-to-get-access-token-for-google-oauth), there's no leading question mark in the parameters.

There *is* a Google .NET OAuth library, but I was not able to get it working easily, and ~50,000 lines of code is more than I'd like to study if I have a choice.  I prefer to write something clean from the ground up than to blindly copy over a bunch of libraries, cargo cult-style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it.  The `redirect_uri` used to request tokens needs to match what was used when getting the authorization code.  Here's my working code to get an auth code:

```
private const string  BaseAuthorizationUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
public string  GetAuthorizationUrl(string clientId, IEnumerable<string> scopes)
    {
    var  parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
        { "response_type",   "code" },
        { "client_id",       clientId },
        { "redirect_uri",    RedirectUrl },
        { "scope",           String.Join(" ", scopes) },
        { "approval_prompt", "auto" }
        };
    return WebUtilities.BuildUrl(BaseAuthorizationUrl, parameters);
    }
```

...here's my code to get an access token and a refresh token:

```
private const string  BaseAccessTokenUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
public void  GetTokens(string clientId, string clientSecret, string authorizationCode, out string accessToken, out string refreshToken)
    {
    var  parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
        { "code",          authorizationCode },
        { "redirect_uri",  RedirectUrl },  // Must match that used when authorizing an app
        { "client_id",     clientId },
        { "scope",         String.Empty },
        { "client_secret", clientSecret },
        { "grant_type",    "authorization_code" }
        };
    string   rawJson    = WebUtilities.Post(BaseAccessTokenUrl, parameters, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    dynamic  parsedJson = JsonUtilities.DeserializeObject(rawJson);
    accessToken  = parsedJson.access_token;
    refreshToken = parsedJson.refresh_token;
    }
```

...here's the code to get a fresh access token:

```
public string  GetAccessToken(string clientId, string clientSecret, string refreshToken)
    {
    var  parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
        { "client_id",     clientId },
        { "client_secret", clientSecret },
        { "refresh_token", refreshToken },
        { "grant_type",    "refresh_token" }
        };
    string   rawJson    = WebUtilities.Post(BaseAccessTokenUrl, parameters, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    dynamic  parsedJson = JsonUtilities.DeserializeObject(rawJson);
    return parsedJson.access_token;
    }
```

Comment: I 've still the same problem, I 'm trying it from raw C++. Always invalid_request.

Comment: @Michael: If you'd like to open a question with more specifics, I can try to help.  Have you reviewed the literature, so to speak?  There are a lot of questions and answers out there (OAuth is a pain, you're not the only one!).

Comment: I finally found it. The usual typo error which can't be detected because of stupid error messages like 'invalid request'.

Thx for your efforts.

Comment: @Michael what was your typo error? Got the same "invalid_request" stupid message